# Stop an anchor from loading on javascript confirm

Tags: javascript

I was under the impression that this was formed correctly, but here it is forwarding to the anchor href (clicking through? what should I call this?) whether or not the user selects cancel or okay.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myconfirm(my_string)                                                 
{                       
 var agree = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove ' + my_string + '?');
 if(agree)                                                                       
 {                                                                               
  return true;                                                            
 }       
 else                                                                            
 {                                                                               
  return false;
 }
}                                                                                       
</script>
```

and the anchor

```
<a href="example.com/?remove=yes" onclick="myconfirm('my_string')">My String</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the onclick handler. Do

```
onclick="return myconfirm('my_string');"
```

Also, you can shorten that if clause to just

```
return agree;
```

Or even just

```
return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove ' + my_string + '?');
```

Answer (score 2):

Matti's right about the need to return something. However:

```
<a href="example.com/?remove=yes" onclick="myconfirm('my_string')">My String</a>
```

*Don't* use a link for this. Anything that has an active effect like a removal should be a form with `method="post"`, not a form or link that causes `GET`, and the server-side script that does the removing should *only* accept POST requests.

Accepting GET for non-idempotent actions, as well as being against the standard, can lead to a variety of [amusing problems](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx).

You can style a form submit button so it doesn't *look* like a button, if you really want to:

```
<form class="confirm" method="post" action="/remove" title="remove my string"><div>
    <input type="submit" class="unbutton" value="My String" />
</div></form>

.unbutton {
    border: none; padding: 0;
    background: transparent; color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can also avoid having to use inline event handler attributes by assigning them from JS:

```
// Find forms with confirm class and bind to them
//
for (var i= document.forms.length; i-->0;)
    if (document.forms[i].className==='confirm')
        document.forms[i].onsubmit= getConfirmation;

// Prompt user to allow submission or not
//
function getConfirmation() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you wish to '+this.title+'?');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return false in the onclick to stop the event.

```
onclick="if( !myconfirm('my_string') ) { return false; }"
```

Or simply:

```
onclick="return myconfirm('my_string');"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onclick` you should **return** value of `myconfirm`: `onclick="return mycnfirm('my_string')"`. By the way, you could just return the result of `confirm` in your `myconfirm`:

```
 function myconfirm(my_string) {
      return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove ' + my_string + '?');
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Put "javascript:void(0)" as the href and then handle everything in the onclick, including the location.href change, if needed.

Comment: I'd personally avoid doing this. Let the link do what it's best at (linking to a page), let the javascript function do it's thing and focus purely on the logic, and then simply stop the event from propagating if the outcome is false. See below.

Comment: So as a matter of personal taste you downvote me? My solution works and has done so for years, across all browsers.

Comment: The technique has genuine downsides: if JavaScript is disabled, you end up with a link that goes nowhere. See http://jibbering.com/faq/index.html#FAQ4_24 for more reasons why `javascript:` URLs generally shouldn't be used.